# Why does my navigation bar hover not work?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why my hover effect isn't working on my navigation bar, and I was wondering if anyone can point out where I've went wrong?

Here is my html and css:

```
 <div id="nav">
    <a class="selected" href="Property%20Advisor.html">Home</a><a     href="PropAbout.html">About</a><a href="PropContact.html">Contact Us</a>
 </div>



#nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 7%;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
font-family: rosario, sans-serif;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);
background-image: linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);

}
#nav a {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 100%;
padding-top: 1%;
padding-left: 2%;
padding-right: 2%;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
padding-bottom: 1%;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 1px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);
background-image: linear-gradient(#44597F, #021840);

}
#nav homeHover a:hover, onCLick {
background-color: #44597F;
color:orange;
}

.selected {
background-color: #000000;
color: orange;
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/VDmh8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just messed up your CSS target.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDmh8/4/)

You're trying to change `#nav a` I presume, so all you need to do is use the CSS selector - `#nav a:hover`.

Setting a background gradient for both your `nav` and link elements is generally a bad idea.  The two gradients will attempt to fit into different sized spaces and clash together.  Instead, try creating a `nav` with a gradient, and then making transparant buttons above the `nav`, so you don't need to specify a new gradient.  This is a bit difficult to explain, so check below:

For the navigation button, just leave out the background entirely when it isn't being hovered, and it will show the `#nav` color behind, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VDmh8/5/).

As a more general example:

```
#nav{
    /* gradients here! */
}

.button    /* not hovered */
{
    /* Don't set a background color - it will be transparant. */
}

.button:hover    /*the same button when it's hovered. */
{
background: #123456;
}
```

(Also PS: never use something like `height: 7%;` for the `nav`.  It ends up scaling improperly.

[image]

Use a definite height, like `height: 48px`.

If you really want to make a responsive website, a [CSS Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) would be better suited in this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works a charm!
I hadn't thought about the gradient clash that you mentioned, thanks for pointing it out, I'll be sure to remember this in the future!

Comment: Thanks for the example too, that has helped me understand more so!
Also thanks for the tip about the nav bar height, I hadn't realised using percentages would scale incorrectly. I was under the assumption that using percentages for most aspects of my website would then scale it accordingly to a device. Thanks very much for pointing that out and I'll definitely read up on CSS Media Queries.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/VDmh8/3/

You need to change:

```
#nav homeHover a:hover, onCLick {
    background-color: #44597F;
}
```

to:

```
#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #44597F;
    background-image: none;

}
```

because for one, `#nav homeHover a:hover` would select a hovered upon `a` element within an element with tag name `homeHover`  within `#nav`, which won't target the `a` elements that you want.
Also, you need to reset the `background-image` property that you set for your unhovered `a`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I hadn't realised I left the homeHover id tag in, that was an experiment to try get this to work but what you have said makes complete sense! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you have a HomeHover in your css? That way, it looks for #nav, then a HomeHover tag inside the nav and then the anchor tag to match.

## nav a:Hover will do.

1. The background-image seems to be drawn over the background-color. You need to set the background-image to something else on the hover.

   ## nav a:hover {

   ```
   background-color: #44597F;
   background-image: none;
   ```

   }

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xY2p8/)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised I left the homeHover id tag in my code, that was me experimenting trying to solve my problem! Your fiddle works for my hover but it doesn't highlight my selected element, is this the same problem as my hover?